# FirebaseCrashlytics SDK Android

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase

Я только переехал на него с обычного Crashlytics,  и начал тестировать.
краши прилетают мгновенно.

В Crashlytics также есть log, который я хочу посмотреть в Firebase.
Для этого я попытался отправить его так

```
Crashlytics.log("Здесь")
```

Использую

```
object Crashlytics {
    fun log(e: Error){
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(e.printStackTrace().toString())
        Log.d("Error даня", e.printStackTrace().toString())
    }
    fun log(e: Exception){
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(e.toString())
        Log.d("Exception даня2", e.toString())
    }

    fun log(message: String){
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(message)
        Log.d("Exception даня3", message)
    }

    fun setUserId(id: String){
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setUserId(id)
    }

}
```

Но этот log не отображается в Crashlytics

Также я попробовал вот это,

```
try {
            val items = listOf<String>()
            val test = items[20]
            Crashlytics.log("Здесь")
        }
        catch (e : Exception){
            Crashlytics.log(e)
        }
```

Все равно Log не приходят.

Я менял evet type c crashes на Non-Fatal, но там ничего нет.
[image: Non-Fatal]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

нужно использовать для NonFatal

```
try {
        val test = 1000000000000000000L
        count(test.toString())  //error
    }
    catch (e : Exception){
        Crashlytics.log(e)
    }
}
fun count(a: String){
    val test = a.toInt()
    Log.d("This", test.toString())
}
```

где Crashlytics

```
object Crashlytics {
    fun log(e: Throwable){
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)
    }
}
```